# How to use SFML in Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, sfml

I found a way to connect SFML to the Qt Creator environment. I was already delighted, but then I tried to push code using both qt and SFML into the project and nothing worked. The fact is that in order to connect SFML to qt creator, you need to change the .pro file and move some directories with SFML files in the directory of the Qt project. I wrote this in the .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += console

LIBS += -L/Users/vladimirkorsunov/QtProjects/untitled/untitled/Contents/Frameworks/

CONFIG (release, debug|release): LIBS += -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
CONFIG (debug, debug|release): LIBS += -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

INCLUDEPATH += /Users/vladimirkorsunov/QtProjects/untitled/
DEPENDPATH += /Users/vladimirkorsunov/QtProjects/untitled/
```

It works, but I can't use qt in this project, because I removed all, that was in the .pro file before. I tried to add this code after code, which already was in .pro, but it still doesn't work. Can I use both SFML and Qt in one window? For example, draw graphics via SFML and draw GUI via Qt?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=17709.0).

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: My OS is Mac OS Big Sur

Comment: I think in all OS, Procedures are looked the same , you should find the path that installs SFML in your os and then put it in the .pro file. I don't know exactly in Mac but I am sure about ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your **.pro** File :

**In Windows :**

```
LIBS += -LC:/SFML-2.3.1-QT-BUILD/lib

INCLUDEPATH += C:/SFML-2.3.1-QT-BUILD/include
DEPENDPATH += C:/SFML-2.3.1-QT-BUILD/include


CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-main -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -lsfml-audio-d -lsfml-graphics-d -lsfml-main-d -lsfml-network-d -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-system-d
```

**In Ubuntu :**

Just add this in .pro and don't forget to install it by `sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev`

```
LIBS += -lsfml-audio
LIBS += -lsfml-graphics
LIBS += -lsfml-network
LIBS += -lsfml-window
LIBS += -lsfml-system
```

look at [this Site](https://lucidar.me/en/sfml/sfml-part-1-installation-and-first-program/).

The better way is to look at its wiki in Github :
https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Compile-and-Link-SFML-with-Qt-Creator

Comment: I use Mac OS, I checked your link and I did same steps. If I remove first 3 lines in my code, compiler says that it can't find sfml directories. I think that it is because of line "CONFIG  -= qt".  If I add that first 3 lines, compiler says that it can't find qt directories. So I can build my project only with sfml or only with qt. I can't understand, how can I mix original code from .pro File with my to build the project.

Comment: I think in all OS, Procedures are looked the same , you should find the path that installs SFML in your os and then put it in the .pro file. I don't know exactly in Mac but I am sure about ubuntu.

Comment: sorry I don't have Mac OS to test it